# Regular Expression to find a gather only the last element on an array

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract from a string which contains a structure of an array

A simple example should be helpful:

Base string: [1, 2, 3, 10000]

If I use the following reg. ex.

`, (.+?)\]`

The match is `3, 10000`. I need to get only the `10000`.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing this with a regex? Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the string into a list, then get the last element of the list.

Comment: Try this `(\d+)(?=])`

Comment: `import json; json.loads(string)[-1]`. Whether you go that route or the one suggested by Barmar, regex is *definitely* the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Thanks @Eraklon. Working like a charm!

Comment: @Jarod, please elaborate.

Comment: @ViniciusCorreia If you use the capturing group, you can omit the lookahead and match the square bracket instead `(\d+)\]` https://regex101.com/r/2JgIAe/1 Or for the full string, match optional repetitions of a digit, comma and space and capture the last digits `\[(?:\d+, )*(\d+)\]` https://regex101.com/r/86OTc2/1

Answer (score 0):

`.+?` will match commas. Making it non-greedy doesn't force it to start matching later.

Use `[^,]+` to not match a comma there.

```
([^,\s]+)\]
```

will match what you want in the capture group.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!